# Multiple Lines in a cell - Rotate Text

Tags: css

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/1mmh7510/

As you can see a header field `Test.. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`  has been rotated by css `.rotate`

```
.rotate {
    height: 400px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 40px;
}

.rotate > div {
    transform:
    translate(-4px, -5px)
    rotate(-90deg);
    width: 20px;
}
```

The content should fill all the white space in the cell in the next line if necessary. How to fix this?

Example how it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **[writing-mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/)** mixed with rotate property wich defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction.

### Support

It's supported by chrome, firefox 41, internet explorer 9, opera and safari 8

### Syntax

The options are:
    `horizontal-tb | vertical-rl | vertical-lr | sideways-rl | sideways-lr`

```css
.rotate {
    height: 400px;
    width: 40px;
}

.rotate > div {
    -webkit-writing-mode:vertical-rl; 
    -ms-writing-mode:tb-rl; 
    writing-mode:vertical-rl; 
  transform: rotate(-180deg)
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color:#e4e6ea;" border="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="tableheader-row-dashboard">
        <td style="background-color:white;"width="90px"> Date</td>      
        <td style="background-color:white" width="90px">Phone No</td>
        <td style="background-color:white; vertical-align: bottom;" class="rotate" width="10px"><div>Test.. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow-rowd">
        <td class="text">06/11/2015</td>
        <td class="text">1234567890</td>
        <td class="text">X</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not actually how I wanted. I have updated my question with a screenshot example and the text should be roatated from -90 deg (reading from bottom to up)

Comment: That awesome! Thanks. Is there a way to get rid of `width` so I can add much content as I like? I have notice when I add more content, it overlap the cell border